# getBoundingClientRect to detect visibility

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getboundingclientrect

**Background**:
I'm currently working on a project where my JS app is embedded into multiple other (parent) JS applications. Some parent app can show/hide my app by setting display:block/none to some element that contains my app. Other parent apps temporarily remove my app from DOM and reattach it later. Few parent apps use shadow dom, so I do not have the access to the elements in the parent app.

I need a way to check if my app is visible (inside DOM and displayed; don't care about visibility:hidden and doesn't have to be inside the viewport), without changing the parent apps, so I looked into *getBoundingClientRect*.

**Question**:
At least on chrome, *getBoundingClientRect* returns (w:0,h:0,l:0,t:0) if an element or its ancestor has display:none or if it is removed from DOM. I could not find any documentation on the guarantee of this behavior, and I am wondering, if it is safe (in the sense the this logic will not change) to use getBoundingClientRect to check for visibility of an element.

Also I need to know if this behavior is consistent across all major browsers, including FF, IE8+, and Safari. Is this documented anywhere?

Lastly, why (0,0,0,0)? I feel like *getBoundingClientRect* should return null in such cases as (0,0,0,0) actually means something different. Is there a good reason for that?

---

**Edited/Additional Question**:
Thanks istos for pointing out that returning null may break some unsuspecting code, such as:

```
console.log(clientRectObject.height);
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of null
```

Not to complain about the current behavior, but as a design question: instead of null, can returning some illegal Rect values (such as negative width and height) be a more useful alternative?

Comment: Hi - did you get a definitive answer to this question?

Answer (score 3):

First I would look into how popular libraries like jQuery solve a similar problem. Here are some links to jQuery's source:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/var/isHidden.js
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L715
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js

Further more I would search online for any clues including MDN:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect
- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/02/04/getting-element-dimensions-a-follow-up
- http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome
- http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/02/the_cssom_view.html#link5

Unfortunately the best way to check if the behavior of `getBoundingClientRect` is the same in most Browsers is to actually test inside those Browsers. If you do this, please go back to MDN and add your findings.

---

> I feel like getBoundingClientRect should return null in such cases

Although returning null would seem logical in such cases, it isn't actually ideal because normally it returns a **ClientRect** object with top, right, bottom, left, width, and height properties, and code like this would break:

```
console.log(clientRectObject.height);
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of null
```

In other words, the API wouldn't be consistent that way.

Comment: Thanks istos for the links and additional explanations!

Comment: Regarding IE8 - _"width and height are missing in IE8, so compute them manually"_:  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/eaf21ec21d260ff7ed1e5b54e5185de235ff7034